# Use Powershell to save a datatable as a csv

Tags: powershell, csv, datatable

There has to be an easy way to do this. I have a Powershell script which connects to a database and I want to save the resulting datatable as a CSV. Here is the code so far:

```
$connString = "Provider=msdaora;Data Source=MyDatabase;User Id=test;Password=test    
$qry = "select * from employees"
$OLEDBConn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($connString)            
$OLEDBConn.open()            
$readcmd = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
$readcmd.Connection = $OLEDBConn
$readcmd.CommandTimeout = '300'
$readcmd.CommandText = $qry
$da = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($readcmd)            
$dt = New-Object system.Data.datatable            
[void]$da.fill($dt)            
$OLEDBConn.close()
```

Comment: There's a [ConvertTo-Csv](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315253.aspx) cmdlet. You just need to make sure that you pipe in something it can understand.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

this should do it I think:

```
$ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$da.Fill($ds) >$null| Out-Null
$ds.Tables[0] | export-csv tofile.csv -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm. I know next to nothing about Powershell but needed to get this simple data pull running.

Comment: Hold up. Why is `$ds.Tables[0] | export-csv tofile.csv -notypeinformation` different from `export-csv tofile.csv -inputobject $ds.Tables[0] -notypeinformation`??